# Comparing object of two large custom Lists in java

Tags: java, list

I have query on how to compare two lists?
This is my case scenario.
I have two `ArrayList` (`nameList<String>` and `countList<Integer>`). Both lists can contain duplicate values and size of both lists is also same.
Now I have to merge these 2 lists as a key-value pair. For this, I had created a custom List of type Person:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Integer charCount;

    public Person(String name, Integer charCount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.charCount = charCount;
    }

    public String Name() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getCharCount() {
        return charCount;
    }

    public void setCharCount(Integer charCount) {
        this.charCount = charCount;
    }
}

List<Person> plist1 = new ArrayList<Person>();
for (int i=0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
    plist1.add(new Person(nameList.get(i), countList.get(i)));
}
```

This gives me values correctly as I want:
James,5
Charles,6
Lloyd,5
Charles,6

And I have created list for another data, with the exactly same requirement as above,say, `plist2`. Now I have to compare these two lists.
That is, I have to check if name contained in plist1 contains in `plist2` also.

Comment: So you need to simply map the names to their `int` indexes of the other list? In that case instead of making a `Person` in your loop, just use `Map#put` and place them in the `Map` directly.

Comment: Can you share the definition of the Person class?

Comment: In short you want to compare two lists of type List<Person> whether both are identical or not. How about order of elements? Does that matter too or if objects in both lists are same content wise and number wise then also you treat them equal?

Comment: There is not enough information here to provide a good answer.

Comment: @Rogue cant use map because both my lists contains duplicate values and i need to store duplicates also.

Comment: @mettleap shared in my question

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi hi i want to maintain the order as well. Thought to do this by LinkedHashMap. But i was not able to add duplicate keys(name) from my list.

Comment: Hi @Richa, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help if you could clarify a couple things about your question. It may be best to *edit* your question to better specify these. This will help you get better answers faster :) 1.) do you need to **compare** two lists (see if they're equal), or do you need to test whether a list **contains** a given element? 2.) if the first case, do you want strict equality (`list a == list b` if they have the same items, in the same order), order-independent equality (exact same items, any order), or order and duplicate-independent inequality (lists are sets)?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a `Map`. It's fundamentally against the design principles for `Map`

Comment: List can have duplicates but not Set and since you are mentioning only list hence we can have duplicate.

Comment: @RichaSharma: I have posted my answer giving you details what all you need to do and how to list the equality of lists containing Person object. Hope that it clarifies what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the two lists (first by name field and then by the charCount field) using a custom Comparator and then iterate through the lists simultaneously checking if corresponding objects from both lists are same or not.

This would give you whether the two lists are equal in the collection of objects they contain (objects may not be the same order). For example:

```
plist1 --> James,5
           Charles,6
           Lloyd,5
           Charles,6

plist2 --> Lloyd,5
           Charles,6
           James,5
           Charles,6
```

are equal according to the algorithm mentioned above, but the in the following scenario they won't be considered equal,

```
plist1 --> James,7
           Charles,6
           Lloyd,5
           Charles,6

plist2 --> Lloyd,5
           Charles,6
           James,5
           Charles,6
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a complete demo of what you want to do and it is comparing various lists and showing their results. In Person class you need to implement equals method like I did and then just iterate both lists in a for loop and compare both objects at same index as in list. If both lists are of different size then you can simple return false. Check this code.

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Integer charCount;

    public Person(String name, Integer charCount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.charCount = charCount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getCharCount() {
        return charCount;
    }

    public void setCharCount(Integer charCount) {
        this.charCount = charCount;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (o instanceof Person) {
            Person person = (Person) o;
            return person.getName().equals(this.getName())
                    && person.getCharCount().intValue() == this.getCharCount().intValue();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Person("a1", 1), new Person("a2", 2));
        List<Person> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Person("a1", 1), new Person("a2", 2));
        List<Person> list3 = Arrays.asList(new Person("a1", 1), new Person("a3", 3));
        // list4 content same as list1 but order different
        List<Person> list4 = Arrays.asList(new Person("a2", 2), new Person("a1", 1));

        System.out.println(compareList(list1, list2));
        // prints true as both list have same person objects and same order

        System.out.println(compareList(list1, list3));
        // prints false as both list have differing content

        System.out.println(compareList(list2, list3));
        // prints false as both list have differing content

        System.out.println(compareList(list1, list4));
        // prints false as both list have same content but differing order
    }

    public static boolean compareList(List<Person> list1, List<Person> list2) {
        if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            if (!list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```